# OpenLDAP : authentication through "domain\username" or "username@domain"

Tags: ldap, openldap

Is there a way to configure OpenLDAP to use authentication through "domain\username" or "username@domain" instead of (or in addition to) by DN ?
I use openLDAP version 2.4.40.

Answer (score 2):

For simple bind – as far as I know, no.

For SASL PLAIN bind, that should work by default, as long as *saslauthd* is running and understands the exact username format you're trying to use – and as long as your `authz-regexp` settings translate it to a correct DN afterwards.